# Circa le sfumature di significato ottenibili passando da SVO a VSO in alcune frasi

Tags: word-order

In inglese l'ordine di verbo e soggetto determina se una proposizione è interrogativa o affermativa (negativa o meno che sia)¹.

In italiano non è così. Tuttavia ho l'impressione (forse condizionata dal mio essere campano), che il reciproco ordinamento di soggetto e verbo possa avere effetto sull'elemento su cui una frase pone l'"incertezza".

Ad esempio, l'interrogativa

> Pago io il pranzo?

mi sembra associ una certa incertezza su chi effettivalmente pagherà il pranzo; cioè, la domanda viene fatta proprio perché non si è deciso ancora chi lo paga; in qualche modo, sottintende un'altra domanda, *O lo paga qualcun altro?*

Invece, se l'ordine fosse cambiato in questo modo,

> Io pago il pranzo?

mi sembra che all'incertezza di cui prima si sostituisca, o per lo meno si aggiunga, quella circa chi pagherà qualche altra cosa, in quello o in un successivo momento; direi che sottintenda *E qualcun altro paga la benzina?* o *E qualcun altro pagherà la cena?*

Credo che qualcosa di analogo possa accadere per le affermative.

Mi chiedo quindi se esista un materiale che affronti questo tipo di "questioni".

---

Per completezza, ho posto il quesito a mia madre, la quale mi ha detto che quella sfumatura la vedo solo io. Mi chiedo quindi se davvero mi sto immaginando tutto, almeno nel caso dello specifico esempio che ho fatto in alto.

---

(¹) È pur vero che anche in inglese, se chiedi *you want it?*, nessuno resta perplesso per la mancanza do *do* all'inizio della domanda, e nessuno si impressiona se dici *you did it?* invece che *did you do it?*

Comment: C'entra solo indirettamente, ma penso che potrai trovare interessante approfondire qualcosa sui concetti di “tema” e “rema” in linguistica: https://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/struttura-tematica_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano) Vedi per esempio, abbastanza all'inizio, un confronto tra “il mio telefonino non funziona più” e “non mi funziona più neanche il telefonino”.

Comment: @DaG, grazie del link. Argomento molto interessante. Riguardo SV vs VS (ahahah), ho trovato [questo](https://www.treccani.it/magazine/lingua_italiana/speciali/I_perche_dell_italiano_2/02_Bonvino.html).